# .contains() on a list of objects

Tags: java, object, deep-copy

I deep copied a list of objects into another list. 
The problem is using `.contains()` didn't work!  Any ideas?

Comment: Need more than just wording..

Comment: How could we possibly help you without any code, any idea what objects you're deep copying, or anything along those lines?

Comment: I bet this error occurs because `equals()` is not overridden in the class stored in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for this to work you need to override hashcode and equals on the contents of the list. Contains uses these methods, which by default are based on the memory reference so it will only work for a shallow copy.